# Sequelize error: defineCall not defined in Index.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've been receiving this sequelize error

```
/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:508
      this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
                           ^
    TypeError: defineCall is not a function
    at module.exports.Sequelize.import             (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:508:32)
at   /models/Index.js:16:33
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vincentporta/Desktop/RCB_Classwork/cesarcell/models/Index.js:15:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

I've narrowed it down to the commented code in my `Index.js` file below

`"use strict";`

```
var fs        = require("fs");
var path      = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var config    = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config',    'config.json'))[env];
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username,  config.password, config);
var db        = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
  })
```

This commented code below breaks it 
    
    `//.forEach(function(file) {
    //   var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    //   db[model.name] = model;
    // });`

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Does anyone know why this error is occuring?

Comment: Which version of Sequelize are you using?

Comment: @rels Sequelize [Node: 4.4.2, CLI: 2.4.0, ORM: 2.0.0-rc1, mysql: ^2.10.2]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This usually means you're trying to import a non-sequelize object. If the name of your index file is `Index.js` then you need to change it in your filter function (first letter is capital)

```
return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "Index.js");
```

As it is case sensitive. Also check that there aren't any other files in your import folder which don't define sequelize model. If there are just add them to your filter function.

Answer (score 8):

I saw a similar problem just now and the problem was a file that was in the models folder that was not actually a database model. Ensure that your models folder only contains models for your database. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have a circular import, also.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was missing `default`.

This code caused the error:

```
@Table
export class User extends Model<User> {
  @Column
  userId!: number;

  @Column
  tenantId!: number;
}
```

`default` in the class defintion fixed it:

```
@Table
export default class User extends Model<User> {
  @Column
  userId!: number;

  @Column
  tenantId!: number;
}
```