# TypeError: defineCall is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting the error when index.js tries to import the model from members.js, and I can't figure out where I am going wrong. members.js is my only import right now.

Edited to show the complete index.js for clarification on imports and other functions.

index.js

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
let env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
let db = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === ".js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

members.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, type) {
  var Members = sequelize.define('Members', {
    id: {
      type: type.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }
  };
  return Members;
};
```

Comment: Where are you importing sequalize? You could just require it in members.js if you haven't defined it anywhere more central yet.

Comment: It's required in index.js. I added the compete code in the original post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequelize error: defineCall not defined in Index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217802/sequelize-error-definecall-not-defined-in-index-js)

Comment: No, as my filter function should be dynamically filtering against  the basename variable. I have changed const to let and still getting the same error.